# WPF Style Textblock.textWraping is not working

Tags: wpf

Complete novice on WPF here. I want to create some simple grid looking boxes in WPF. And to do so, I have implemented 3*3 grid and now I am trying to set some styles as `Window.Resources` and `Style`s. I created a `Style` for `Border`. Everything I set in this `Style` for `Border` (like `Background`, `CornerRadius`, `TextBlock.Foreground`, `TextBlock.FontSize`) is working as expected. But one thing is not working as it should (according to my understanding. The property `TextBlock.TextWrapping` is not working. If I set this option directly on every `Border` then it works but this is not what I want to learn here.

Why does `TextBlock.TextWrapping` doesnt work when defined as `Style` and what should I do? Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<Window x:Class="Test_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Jocko" Height="800" Width="800">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridCell" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="30"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
        <TextBlock Text="This text should be wraped but it is not"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
        <TextBlock Text="This text should be wraped but it is not"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
        <TextBlock Text="This text should be wraped but it is not"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextWrapping` property is a dependency property defined on `TextBlock`. You cannot set it on another type. When you try to apply it on a `Border`, you will most likely get an error like this.

> The local property "TextWrapping" can only be applied to types derived from "TextBlock"

However, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_DependencyProperty_RegisterAttached_System_String_System_Type_System_Type_) there is a chance that it works, but it is undefined behavior and you should neither use this behavior nor rely on it.

> [...] Although property value inheritance might appear to work for nonattached dependency properties, the inheritance behavior for a nonattached property through certain element boundaries in the runtime tree is undefined. [...]

It works for the other properties of `TextBlock` in your style, because they are defined as [**attached properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_DependencyProperty_RegisterAttached_System_String_System_Type_System_Type_) that can be applied to any element, but `TextWrapping` is not.

> [...] Registering the property as attached effectively makes the attached property a global property to the property system, and assures that property value inheritance works across all boundaries in an element tree. [...]

Create a style for `TextBlock` only, where you define `TextWrapping` and apply it to the `TextBlock`s.

```
<Style x:Key="GridCellTextBlockStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
   <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
</Style>
```

```
<Border Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Style="{StaticResource GridCell}">
   <TextBlock Text="This text is wrapped" Style="{StaticResource GridCellTextBlockStyle}"/>
</Border>
```

Comment: Great this works as charm! :)
Just to be on save side, i moved all properties for textblock under textblock style.